# Custom view's measurements

Tags: android

I am creating a custom view and in the layout file, I set its width to 200dp, and its height to 200dp.

```
<com.example.baoshuai.mydefineview.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:text="Hello,Sunshine"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

I am using `getWidth()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` to get my view's width, the value is not 200dp, but 700dp. Here is where I get the measurements:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    Log.d("get","Width:"+width+" Height:"+height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.d("getMeasured","measuredWidth:"+measuredWidth+" measuredHeight:"+measuredHeight);
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
```

Value you are defining is in `dp`. When you programatically get width and height `int width = getWidth();` value is in pixels.

So it's seems different values but are same.

You can check same by applying values in px in layout and displaying it programatically.

> Refere https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/3817374 to get more information about different units in Android.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've found the mistake.